Is n-gram precision the number of elements in the intersection of one hypothesis and possibly many references?
I was trying to understand how BLEU score works and noticed that if I had to compute the n-gram precisions and have multiple reference sentences, it makes more sense to turn everything into sets to remove duplicates. Order in terms of n-grams does not seem to matter, the order of n-tokens is persisted by n-grams but the order each individial n-gram is irrelevant, so we can indeed just use sets to compute n-gram precision of the hypothesis with respect to many references.
In other words, if I'm given many references and one hypothesis, I compute the n-gram precision by:

Forming two sets, one set is the union of all n-gram sets of all references, the other set consists of all n-grams in the hypothesis. Duplicates are eliminated.
Look for the intersection between both sets. The number of n-grams in that intersection divided by the number of n-grams in the hypothesis set is the n-gram precision.

I think this idea is also backed up by the nltk implementation of BLEU scores.
    # Extracts all ngrams in hypothesis
    # Set an empty Counter if hypothesis is empty.
    counts = Counter(ngrams(hypothesis, n)) if len(hypothesis) >= n else Counter()
    
    # Extract a union of references' counts.
    # max_counts = reduce(or_, [Counter(ngrams(ref, n)) for ref in references])
    max_counts = {}
    for reference in references:
        reference_counts = (
            Counter(ngrams(reference, n)) if len(reference) >= n else Counter()
        )
        for ngram in counts:
            max_counts[ngram] = max(max_counts.get(ngram, 0), reference_counts[ngram])

    # Assigns the intersection between hypothesis and references' counts.
    clipped_counts = {
        ngram: min(count, max_counts[ngram]) for ngram, count in counts.items()
    }

Am I misunderstanding something or this a correct way of computing n-gram precision?

NLTK realisation is correct, you can read more in original paper.

I understand that, I just wanted to know if describing it in terms of intersection and union is also valid or if there is a catch I missed. I assume there is actually a catch because they use 'clipped counts' which doesn't mean no duplicates. So a 1-to-1 analogy with set theory is not possible, although very close. Unfortunate.

@Yuirike yes, you are right, but no one can forbid you to use your custom BLEU metric if you want, you just have to explain, why you prefer sets intersection instead of counting

Okay, I answer my own question.
The idea of using intersection and unions isn't actually far off from what we actually do but the approach illustrated is wrong because:

Clipping counts is not the same unique elements in sets.
It fails to account for what happens for multiple reference sentences.

Example:
Hypothesis: 'so so'
Reference1: 'so'
Reference2: 'so'

The set approach would yield 100% uni-gram precision although it should be 50%.
Instead of doing sets directly, we use dictionaries that keep track of the counts:
Hypothesis: {'so':2}
Reference1: {'so':1}
Reference2: {'so':1}

And we should not merge Reference1 and Reference2 dictionaries directly and get something like {'so':2}, that would be wrong. Instead, we take the max count when combining the Reference dictionaries.
Example 2
Hypothesis: 'I luv cats so so much'
Reference1: 'I love cats so so much'
Reference2: 'I luv cats so much'

The uni-gram precision should be 100% in this case because we have one reference where 'so' appears twice, so the max count of 'so' allowed based on reference is 2. Not 1 and not 3.
A code based implementation that seems to work would be:
from collections import defaultdict
def precision(hyp : list[list[tuple[str]]], ref : list[list[tuple[str]]]):
    actual_hyp = hyp[0] # list[tuple[str]]
    hyp_grams = defaultdict(int)
    for n_gram in actual_hyp: hyp_grams[n_gram]+=1
    
    ref_grams = defaultdict(int)
    tmp = []
    for seq in ref:
        dic = defaultdict(int)
        for n_gram in seq: dic[n_gram]+=1
        tmp.append(dic)
    
    for dic in tmp:
        for key in dic:
            if key in ref_grams:
                ref_grams[key] = max(ref_grams[key], dic[key])
            else:
                ref_grams[key] = dic[key]
    
    
    found = set(hyp_grams).intersection(set(ref_grams))
    correct = 0
    for n_gram in found:
        correct += min(hyp_grams[n_gram], ref_grams[n_gram])
    
    total = sum(hyp_grams.values())
    return correct / total

In this approach I implemented something that computes the n-grams prior. That function returns lists of n_grams per sequence. So you can pass in multiple reference sequences and get out a list of n_grams per each sequences. In case of hypothesis, I know it's always only one hypothesis, so I directly access the first one when comptuing the precision. The interesting part is how I merge the reference n_grams together, I pick the max number of n_grams that one reference sequence has, I do not add them together.
